# Суть проблемы исключающего или

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Недавно я стал интересоваться нейронными сетями и машинным обучением. В какой то статье прочитал, что нейронная сеть, которая решает проблему XOR, это своего рода "Hello world"-программа в машинном обучении.

Вопрос такой. **В чем суть проблемы XOR?**
В гугле есть информация как ее решить и я понимаю что выполняет оператор XOR, но я все равно не могу понять саму суть задачи и что нужно решить.

Comment: Читали? http://robocraft.ru/blog/algorithm/558.html

Comment: @ВикторБоровлёв, именно эту статью не читал. Спасибо за наводку :)

Answer (score 2):

Суть проблемы XOR в том, что простейшая нейроная сеть, Перцептрон, представляет из себя одну разделяющую черту, а представление оператора XOR:

```
1 |1    0
  |
0 |0____1
  0     1
```

Как видите, нельзя разделить одной линией на два класса - нули и единицы.
Подробный разбор по [ссылке](http://robocraft.ru/blog/algorithm/558.html).

Comment: зачем нам строить какую-то черту?

Comment: @RezvanovMaxim Обратитесь к ссылке для понимания, что такое нейросеть. Коротко, принято рассматривать нейросеть как функцию, которая разделяет пространство решений. В двумерном пространстве (у XOR два аргумента) функция это линия, а перцептрон это линейная функция, то есть черта (прямая линия).

Comment: а в трехмерном пространстве получается гиперплоскость?

Comment: @RezvanovMaxim Правильно. В любом n-мерном пространстве именно однослойный нейрон (перцептрон) это гиперплоскость.

Comment: Нафига мне код?У меня своего полно.Я просто хотел рассказать правду,чтобы не было полу-фейкового понимания нейросети.

Comment: Я хотел сказать что XOR реально не разделим ни одной нейросетью,это было тоже дополнительной информацией к ответу,но пошутил про 500 рублей,что пришлю кто мне даст код,реально разделяющий XOR,это было для веселости)