# Реализация XOR на нейросети - вопрос по кол-ву нейронов

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

В понимании того, что такое нейросети очень помогла [эта статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/313216/) Хабра. В принципе, по ней я и пробую.

Дело в том, что, похоже, двух скрытых нейронов недостаточно для обучения нейросети XOR-у. По крайней мере, по этому алгоритму.
Потому как в итоге, для входных значений 1 и 1 результат в процессе обучение застревает на 0.52-0.57. Т.е., грубо говоря посередине. Это спустя 1.000.000 эпох.

Пробовал увеличить кол-во нейронов до 3, перетягивание каната (результата для 1 и 1) сохраняется примерно до 70.000 эпох, потом система находит решение.

Большее кол-во нейронов позволяет быстрее обучить систему? Или как?
Как вообще определить кол-во нейронов на слое и кол-во слоев? Я нигде не видел точного пояснения на этот счет.

Comment: Дело не в скорости, а в том что xor принципиально невозможно реализовать на однослойной сети. См например вопрос [Суть проблемы исключающего или](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674268/Суть-проблемы-исключающего-или)

Comment: Но у меня же заработало на однослойной. Получается 2 входных нейрона, 3 скрытых и 1 выходной. За слои считаются только слои со скрытыми нейронами.

Comment: У вас обучение застревает на середине, это значит, что например при любых входных данных у вас ответ будет 0.5 вместо 0 или 1. Это значит что однослойный не заработал.

Comment: Не, в том то и дело, у меня застревает, когда на скрытом слое 2 нейрона (как и рекомендовано в туториале). Когда я увеличиваю до 3, все работает.

Comment: А про bias не забыли?

Comment: Знаю, что это такое, но в статье не говорилось, что его в данном случае надо использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, дело было в том, что у меня была задана слишком высокая скорость обучения (0.7, как в статье). Поэтому происходило примерно следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того, как я уменьшил скорость обучения до 0.1, за ~100 000 эпох все рассчиталось.

К сожалению, по остальным аспектам моего вопроса нормальных ответов я так и не увидел.